# Sql-unable to get record with recent date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that reads like this:

```
Select a.student_class,
       b.student_id,
       b.student_name,
       b.student_exam,
       b.exam_name,
       b.exam_completion_date
from   exam_table b inner join student_table a on a.student_id=b.student_id
where  exam_name='cs'
```

If supposing the student has taken the exam multiple times I would have multiple records in my exam table.I want the latest exam_completion_date

I tried the below modified query (which do not appear to work):

```
Select a.student_class, 
       b.student_id,
       b.student_name,
       b.student_exam,
       b.exam_name,
       Max(b.exam_completion_date)
from   exam_table b inner join student_table a on a.student_id=b.student_id
where  exam_name='cs'
group  by a.student_class,
          b.student_id,
          b.student_name,
          b.student_exam,
          b.exam_name,
          b.exam_completion_date
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove `exam_completion_date` from the `GROUP BY` clause and you should be good.

Comment: Can you show us your schema, please?

Comment: On a side note: Your data model looks weird. Why is there a student name in the exams table? Do the students change their names with every exam they take? I'd expect three tables instead: student, exam, and a bridge table student_exam. I'd also recommend mnemonic alias names, like `s` for student and `e` for exam. `a` and `b` instead make the query harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your `group by` is too broad. It will split into groups with all the same...

- student_class
- student_id
- student_name
- student_exam
- exam_name
- exam_completion_date

Every group will have a different `exam_completion_date`, so `max(exam_completion_date)` will simply be `exam_completion_date`.

It's a common mistake to simply put all the same columns from the `select` into the `group by`, but that isn't necessary. It's enough to add the primary keys to uniquely identify a row. For example, assuming `student_id` is the primary key of `student_table`, `group by student_id`. `student_name` is not necessary as it is dependent on the `student_id`. (`student_name` should not probably not be duplicated in `exam_table` unless your students can offer a different name for each exam).

It's also preferable to group by ID, not by name, else you risk unknowingly grouping two things together. If there are two exams with the same name, `group by exam_name` will treat them as a single exam. `group by exam_id` will separate them.

To group by student and exam, this should be all you need.

```
group by b.student_id, b.exam_id
```